# Understanding error code in Here Map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

I'm using Here Map iOS SDK version 3.16.3
I am using the Here map to plot the route with multiple waypoints. When calculating the ETA in the route I'm getting the error **NMARoutingErrorViolatesOptions**. When I checked further inside the **NMARouteResult** class, Property **violatedOptions** inside the class is returning **4096** in an array. Please find the comments of the **violatedOptions** property below.

```
  /**
    * NSArray of NSNumber objects, one per route calculated,
    * representing which options (if any) were violated for the
    * corresponding route. The NSNumber objects should be converted to
    * NSUInteger before checking. The value will be an OR combination of
    * NMARoutingOption and `NMARoutingViolatedOption` values, or
    * NMARoutingViolatedOptionNone if no options were violated. If route calculation
    * failed, the array will contain a single object containing all the routing
    * options (if any).
    */
    
     @property (nonatomic, readonly, nullable) NSArray <NSNumber *> *violatedOptions;
```

I have set the routing option in **NMACoreRouter** object as **NMARoutingOptionAvoidBoatFerry**.

> NMARoutingOptionAvoidBoatFerry          = 1 << 0,

Below is the enum for violated options and I am trying to find the exact error that has occurred in my route.

```
/**
 * Implicit routing options that may be violated by routing calculation operations.
 *
 * @note Violations which depend on traffic data (e.g. BlockedRoad) will only be returned if
 * the traffic feature is available.
 */
// The violatedOptions value returned from NMARouter will be an OR
// combination of NMARoutingOption and NMARoutingViolatedOption values. Thus the
// NMARoutingViolatedOption values offset from a larger value to leave room
// for NMARoutingOption values to grow in the future.
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, NMARoutingViolatedOption) {
    /** The returned route does not violate any options */
    NMARoutingViolatedOptionNone NS_SWIFT_NAME(none)                       = 0,
    /** The route passes through a blocked road (e.g. due to construction or a traffic accident) */
    NMARoutingViolatedOptionBlockedRoad NS_SWIFT_NAME(blockedRoad)         = 1 << 12,
    /** The route passes through a road with a time-based turn restriction */
    NMARoutingViolatedOptionTurnRestriction NS_SWIFT_NAME(turnRestriction) = 1 << 13,
    /** The route's start direction is not as requested */
    NMARoutingViolatedOptionStartDirection NS_SWIFT_NAME(startDirection)   = 1 << 14,
    /** The route uses roads or turns which are permanently forbidden for given truck */
    NMARoutingViolatedPermanentTruckRestriction                            = 1 << 15,
    /** The route uses roads that belong to restricted areas. */
    NMARoutingViolatedOptionZoneRestriction NS_SWIFT_NAME(zoneRestriction) = 1 << 16
};
```

Since the binary code of 4096 is 1000000000000 = 1 << 12. In the code documentation

> The violatedOptions value returned from NMARouter will be an OR
> combination of NMARoutingOption and NMARoutingViolatedOption values.
> Thus the NMARoutingViolatedOption values offset from a larger value to
> leave room for NMARoutingOption values to grow in the future.

> 1 << 0 (NMARoutingOption) OR (some value in NMARoutingViolatedOption) = 1 << 12 (4096)

Is this the correct logic to get the value of NMARoutingViolatedOption? None of the **NMARoutingViolatedOption** values doesn't fit correctly in the above logic. Can anyone help me understand this better?

Comment: Your logic is correct. Seems you have already answered your question, take a close look.
4096 is equivalent to 1<<12 in binary. This is equal to blocked road.

    /** The route passes through a blocked road (e.g. due to construction or a traffic accident) */
    NMARoutingViolatedOptionBlockedRoad NS_SWIFT_NAME(blockedRoad)         = 1 << 12,

Answer (score 0):

You can check violated errors like this:

Objective-C:

```
NSInteger violatedOption = [routeResult.violatedOptions[0] integerValue];

if (violatedOption & NMARoutingViolatedOptionBlockedRoad) {
      // handle blocked road violated option (4096)
}
```

Swift:

```
guard let violatedOption = routeResult?.violatedOptions?.first?.intValue else { return }

if (violatedOption & NMARoutingViolatedOption.blockedRoad.rawValue) != 0 {
      // handle blocked road violated option (4096)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One addition to the answer of @dashchark:

violatedOptions can also contain one or more "NMARoutingOption" options to which the calculated route is not satisfying.
So also check all possible enum values of NMARoutingOption

Swift:

```
guard let violatedOption = routeResult?.violatedOptions?.first?.uintValue else { return }

if (violatedOption & NMARoutingOption.avoidTunnel.rawValue) != 0 {
    // route does not satisfy the route option "avoid tunnel"
}

if (violatedOption & NMARoutingOption.avoidTollRoad.rawValue) != 0 {
    // route does not satisfy the route option "avoid tunnel"
}
...
```